# Small String that continuously repeated in Big String

Tags: python, string

I am trying to get a length of a Small string that repeats large string continuously in Python

I Tried...

```
def repeats(string):
for x in range(1, len(string)):
    substring = string[:x]

    if substring * (len(string)//len(substring))+(substring[:len(string)%len(substring)]) == string:
        return "break"

print(len(substring))
```

But it's long..
Plese Give me your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a regex `re.findall` approach here:

```py
def longest_repeat(x):
    matches = re.findall(r'(.+)\1+', x)
    matches.sort(key=lambda s: len(s), reverse=True)
    if not matches:
        return ''
    else:
        return matches[0]

inp = ["agtcaggtccaggtccgatcgaatac", "agtcgggggggatta", "agtctgcatgac"]
for i in inp:
    output = longest_repeat(i)
    print(i + ', ' + output)
```

This prints:

```
agtcaggtccaggtccgatcgaatac, caggtc
agtcgggggggatta, ggg
agtctgcatgac,
```